# Loved in a sentence

Tags: past-tense, past-participles, present-simple

> My husband **loved** having me over in his office.
>
> My husband **loves** having me over in his office.

My questions:

1. Does **loved** here refer to the simple past or the past participle ?
2. Do both the sentences have a correct **grammar point**? Do they have a same or a different meaning?
3. Do these two sentences convey different meanings?
4. How do I differentiate the **simple past** and  the **past participle** in a sentence ?

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence means that he enjoys it when she visits his office.

The first could be understood in two different ways. *Either* he enjoyed a particular occasion when she visited the office, *or* he used to enjoy visits which don't happen any more (maybe he is dead, or no longer works there).

*He loved* (past tense). *He loves* (present tense).